# How to properly seed a mongoDb collection with two many-to-many self-relations via prisma

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, prisma

I have a collection in mongoDb with two many-to-many self-relations. The idea is that each document can have 0 to many successors and 0 to many predecessors. The collection is generated via Prisma using the following schema:

```
model ChapterSegment {
  id               String             @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  chapter          Chapter            @relation(fields: [chapterId], references: [id])
  chapterId        String             @db.ObjectId
  successorIds     String[]           @db.ObjectId
  predecessorIds   String[]           @db.ObjectId
  successors       ChapterSegment[]   @relation("successors-predecessors", fields: [successorIds], references: [id])
  predecessors     ChapterSegment[]   @relation("successors-predecessors", fields: [predecessorIds], references: [id])
}
```

What I don't seem to understand however is how to import data into this model using the [prisma client](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries#nested-writes) in typescript.

I have tried using a nested create but this quickly becomes complex because of its recursive nature. It works for a few records but its impossible to maintain for larger amounts of data.

I have also tried using simple creates, storing the results in typescript variables and connecting them in-memory and via the prisma connect keyword, this also is very tedious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a two-step process for importing data.

1. You create the `ChapterSegment` documents, and then you establish the relationships between them using the update method. This will make the process less complex and easier to maintain. Here's an example using the Prisma client:

   Assuming you have the data for the ChapterSegment documents in an array, first create the documents without relationships:

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';
const prisma = new PrismaClient();

const chapterSegmentsData = [
  // Your data here in the format
  // { chapterId: '...', successors: [...], predecessors: [...] }
];

// Create ChapterSegment documents without relationships
const createdChapterSegments = await Promise.all(
  chapterSegmentsData.map(async (data) => {
    const { chapterId, successors, predecessors, ...rest } = data;
    return prisma.chapterSegment.create({
      data: {
        chapterId,
        ...rest,
      },
    });
  })
);
```

2. Now that you have created the `ChapterSegment` documents, you can establish the relationships between them using the update method:

```
// Helper function to find a ChapterSegment's id by its original data
const findIdByData = (data) => {
  const found = createdChapterSegments.find(
    (created) => created.chapterId === data.chapterId
  );
  return found ? found.id : null;
};

// Update relationships
await Promise.all(
  chapterSegmentsData.map(async (data) => {
    const id = findIdByData(data);
    if (!id) return;

    const successorIds = data.successors.map(findIdByData).filter((id) => id);
    const predecessorIds = data.predecessors
      .map(findIdByData)
      .filter((id) => id);

    await prisma.chapterSegment.update({
      where: { id },
      data: {
        successorIds: { set: successorIds },
        predecessorIds: { set: predecessorIds },
      },
    });
  })
);
```

With this approach, you create the `ChapterSegment` documents first, then update the relationships separately. This should be more manageable and easier to maintain.

Comment: Excellent answer, using this approach all seed data can be stored in json files with a flat structure, thanks a lot!

Comment: I am glad to hear that it was useful :)